# Using OVER function with generate_series

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following schema in my database:

```
CREATE TABLE survey_results (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    scores jsonb DEFAULT '{}'::jsonb,
    created_at timestamp without time zone,
    updated_at timestamp without time zone  
);

INSERT INTO survey_results (id, scores, created_at, updated_at)
    VALUES (1, '{"medic": { "social": { "total": "high" } } }', '2018-01-10', '2018-01-11');

INSERT INTO survey_results (id, scores, created_at, updated_at)
    VALUES (2, '{"medic": { "social": { "total": "high" } } }', '2018-01-12', '2018-01-12');
```

and the following query:

```
SELECT date::date, coalesce(positive, 0.00) as positive
FROM generate_series('2018-01-10'::date, '2018-01-12', '1d') s(date)
LEFT JOIN (
    -- your query
    SELECT
      distinct(date(survey_results.created_at)),
      ROUND(
        COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE (
          scores#>>'{medic,social,total}' in('high'))) OVER(order by date(survey_results.created_at)
        ) * 1.0 /
        (
          GREATEST(
            COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE (scores#>>'{medic,social,total}' in('high','medium','low')
        )
      ) OVER(order by date(survey_results.created_at)), 1.0))* 100, 2
    )
     AS positive
      FROM survey_results
      WHERE  
        survey_results.created_at::date >= '2018-01-10'
        AND survey_results.created_at::date <= '2018-01-12'
      GROUP BY date, scores
    -- your query
    ) q USING(date)
ORDER BY date ASC;
```

which returns following results:

```
date        positive
2018-01-10  100
2018-01-11  0
2018-01-12  100
```

but the problem is that when on some day there was no results it should get the same data as on the previous day, so it should look like this:

```
date        positive
2018-01-10  100
2018-01-11  100
2018-01-12  100
```

I was thinking about using `OVER` function here but I was not able to make it work. Is there any way of doing that?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/0cd2c/1

Comment: what if `2018-01-12` was also zero, would you want to carry `100` over till the next non-zero date?

Comment: Yes, this should work this way.

Comment: If you explained what the logic is supposed to do, it would be much easier to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a cumulative `count(*)` as a window function to designate partitions (groups with leading non-null value and consecutive null values). Next, add one more outer select with the window function `first_value()` in these partitions:

```
SELECT *, first_value(positive) OVER (PARTITION BY part ORDER BY date)
FROM (
    SELECT date::date, positive, count(positive) OVER (ORDER BY date) as part
    FROM generate_series('2018-01-09'::date, '2018-01-12', '1d') s(date)
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
          distinct(date(survey_results.created_at)),
          ROUND(
            COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE (
              scores#>>'{medic,social,total}' in('high'))) OVER(order by date(survey_results.created_at)
            ) * 1.0 /
            (
              GREATEST(
                COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE (scores#>>'{medic,social,total}' in('high','medium','low')
            )
          ) OVER(order by date(survey_results.created_at)), 1.0))* 100, 2
        )
         AS positive
          FROM survey_results
          WHERE  
            survey_results.created_at::date >= '2018-01-09'
            AND survey_results.created_at::date <= '2018-01-12'
          GROUP BY date, scores
        ) q USING(date)
    ) q
ORDER BY date ASC;
```

[SqlFiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/0cd2c/11)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cumulative function, such as `max()`:

```
select, date::date, coalesce(positive, 0.00),
        max(positive) over (order by date::date)
```

This works if your data is increasing.